# Getting macOS’s WebDAV service to work

Tags: networking, macos, mac, webdav, macos-mojave

I thought I would get WebDAV up and running simply by 
`sudo wfsctl start`
[this guide doesn’t make it anymore complicated either](https://news.mynavi.jp/article/osxhack-202/)

It appears to be running but every client fail with a timeout unable to connect/authenticate
http://imac.local:443/sharedFolder

**What do we need for it to work?**

- Make sure the port is right.
- Use the share command to assign shared folders.
- Use the diagnose command to troubleshoot

Comment: Are you sure it is running? What is the result of `sudo wfsctl status`? If it shows `enabled` then what is the result of `sudo wfsctl shares`? Does that show the directory you are trying to share? If so, what are you trying to connect to imac.local with? Another computer? A phone? From said device, can you ping imac.local?

Comment: Safari on iPhone gives the “It’s Working!” message for imac.local and the status does show `enabled` and `shares` gives the desired folders and marks them as (WFS yes)

Comment: Before adding another device to the equation, try to connect to the webdav share from the iMac that you're running it from. Once you've confirmed that webdav is `enabled`, select "Connect to Server..." from the Finder's Go menu item and enter https://imac.local/ in the field. You will need to login with a user on the machine. Does that work?

Comment: It’s the same behavior, it asks for username/password try to connect until timeout and present the exceptionally helpful message of failed to connect/contact the admin. https & http aren’t the same although both fail

Comment: Are there any relevant logs in the Console?

Comment: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using MacBook.local. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message !!!?